# STS, pom.xm error, Multiple annotations found at this line

Tags: spring, pom.xml

I just created a simple project from Spring Template using STS IDE,but the pom.xm shows an error :

```
Multiple annotations found at this line:
    - Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:
     2.4.3:resources (execution: default-resources, phase: process-resources)
    - Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:
     2.4.3:testResources (execution: default-testResources, phase: process-test-resources)
```

I spent long time searching what is the problem but could not find a solution, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try running mvn eclipse:eclipse on the root folder of the project (You will need to download maven and add it to the classpath first).